# My counter will not increase C#

Tags: c#, count, break

I'm using C# to make a receipt program and I've got it working, except for the counter. The number will only remain as the number in the break and not increase. I've tried to change the number, but that does not appear to work.

```
        decimal count;
        decimal price;
        decimal subtotal;
        decimal tax;
        decimal total;

        subtotal = 0;
        count = 0;

        for (count = 1; count <= 10; ++count)
        {
            if (count == 1)
                break;
            count = count + 1;
        }

        while (count <=10)
        {
            Console.Write("Item{0}", count);
            Console.Write( "        Enter price:$ ");
            price = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (price == -1)
                break;
            subtotal = price + subtotal;

        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nNumber of Items:{0}", count);

       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you understand the concept behind the `break` keyword? Here's [some doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4.aspx)

Comment: Simply debugging your code would make it pretty obvious where the problem lies.

Comment: And you're increasing `count` into the loop as well. I think you need to lookup how `for` loops work. And also `while`, since I'm pretty sure you'll be stuck in an infinite loop/skip over it once you figure out how a `for` loop works.

Comment: Deleted my other comment.  Doesn't really seem like you're thinking of `continue` either, since no matter what you put there you'll never increase the value of count (which will also always make the next loop an infinite one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is breaking at this line and execution stops:

```
if (count == 1)
    break;
```

Since you initially set `count` to 1 in the `for` loop, your `if` statement is executed on the first loop iteration and `break` is called.  Once you remove or modify that code, it should work as expected.

Comment: Not really. There is also an infinite loop in the code, as-is.

Comment: @TiesonT. - Fair enough, I was only pointing out the issue with the initial logic.  A rewrite would probably be a good idea here to restructure the loops into something a bit more effective.